# Blocking and non-blocking file descriptors under the hood

Tags: c, linux, sockets, tcp, network-programming

I've spent already some weeks investigating how Linux tcp/ip stack works. And the most difficult part for me is network sockets. I have a lot of questions but I will do my best to be as specific as possible. Let's talk about udp sockets for simplicity.

1. As I understand `recvfrom()` is just a case of `read()` syscall for copying data from the socket buffer inside kernel to the user space. I looked through the implementation and all user space operations end at the point `sock->ops->some-protocol-dependent-operation` (i.e. `sock->ops->recvmsg`). Correct me if I am wrong.
2. What happen next? Logically, we need to check if socket has data for us and than return (copy) it according to the protocol(UDP) structure implemented in the kernel TCP/IP stack. Again correct me if I missed something important.
3. And here is the **'darkest'** part for me. I know that sockets (roughly speaking opened file descriptors) could be blocking and non-blocking. I know that network sockets are blocking by default (**Why so?**). What I cannot understand is how kernel blocks them. I tried to find this in Linux kernel sources but it's pretty hard. What I understand from the bunch of same questions is:
   When NIC has data arrived it signals cpu and pass it through the network stack up to the TCP layer. On that level we have opened socket and our network stack copy incoming data to the socket buffer. Then some magical system (**what is the name and how does It poll the buffer?**) signals that there is an event on a fd, so `recvfrom` becomes unblocked. The next question: Is `recvfrom` just make process sleep (**what mechanism is used? sigwait?**). Or Is there a long polling somewhere inside of this stacktrace?
4. Does turning fd to non-blocking mode mean using epoll somewhere inside? Why cannot I just use it in my program to check that fd is ready and than call recvfrom ? Or this is a bad practice?

Guys, really sorry for so broad topic but everything is interconnected and I cannot split it to different parts.

Comment: I'm not a Linux kernel expert, but ... The kernel does not retrieve data on recvfrom. It retrieves data when they arrive at the network card and puts the payload into the receive buffer. On recvfrom or similar it just checks the buffer and if there are data in it it will return with these data. Otherwise the process will be stopped - nothing special for sockets here but also done when scheduling etc. And the process will be woken up if new data get put into the sockets receive buffer since now they can be returned inside recvfrom.

Comment: How familiar are you with the basic concept of multitasking and how it's implemented?  That's at the heart of your question.  Without that background, it may be hard to answer your question without writing a short textbook on OS theory and implementation.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich
 *The kernel does not retrieve data on recvfrom....*.  
Yes this what I said in my question.
*Otherwise the process will be stopped - nothing special for sockets here but also done when scheduling etc.*
Yes it's also clear from my question 
*And the process will be woken up if new data get put into the sockets receive buffer*


And this is part I cannot understand, where is this mechanism ? What is magic behind receive buffer? Who raise an event that buffer was changed ?

Comment: @NateEldredge I am really not an expert, but I just need a direction where to investigate. As I said in the previous comment the main question is: Who is responsible for raising events and sending signals when fd data changed ? I do not think multitasking is a core of that

Comment: Well, it's not a signal - the interrupt handler that receives the packet from the network card will check the sending host and port, match it with the open socket, and check a list of processes waiting for I/O on that socket (which your process was added to when you called `recvfrom()`).  It will see your process there and mark it as runnable, so it can be woken up when the scheduler runs next.  The question of what it means for the process to be marked sleeping or runnable is about multitasking, that's what I meant by that.

Comment: @NateEldredge Thank you! It is now much more clear for me!

Comment: @NateEldredge Probably you can post your answer so I will accept it

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a correct approach for the first question

Then, UDP is not connected -> you will only need one recvfrom (). However TCP is connected and so you will "keep" your connexion and so you will also maybe need several recv() (and so to make a loop) [I don't really know if it is what you want to know...]

recv() and recvfrom() are blocking functions (they wait a new message), and so to unblock them you will need fcntl () [e.g: `fcntl(sockfd, F_SETFL, fcntl(sockfd, F_GETFL) | O_NONBLOCK)`]. And then, you can verify that you have new message with loops. But I think this is easier using select () (you have'nt to use fcntl() and it allow to use a socket only when it is activated by an activity [reception here]).

I hope this will answer your questions (and I hope I say nothing bad)

Comment: I know all of that.. But my question is more about the internal mechanism of blocking fd. And how does the kernel listen for changes on its data buffer...